# How to add a panel and dock it on to metrocontroltab

Tags: vb.net, panel, metroframework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKj3g.jpg)Hi everyone so Ive been following a tutorial where he put a panel and docked it onto the metro tab control. He did it just fine but when i did it it displays an error. I tried reinstalling the metro framework a couple of times but it wont work. Im new to programming i hope someone can help me

Comment: Well, think the message really gives you the answer to your problem.  Why though, are you sure you're not missing a step in your tutorial, maybe you need to be adding a TabPage first?

Comment: It actually have a tabpage, Im also confused why he's addng a panel to a metro tab control but since im new to programming Im just following his tutorial

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

so after thinking about it I finally got a solution, I actually missed a step where he copy and paste panels on the tabpage, Whenever I drag the panel in the metro tab it says an error so what i did is i copied a panel and pasted it on the inside the tab index. Thank you so much